# Buggy behaviour of WebBrowser control in child windows

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

[image]
The big red border marks the actual parent window of the nested `<WebBrowser>` control. This behaviour occurs if I try to scroll down. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

I have tried the Telerik RadHtmlPlaceholder, as well. But this is even worse, atm.

Comment: well..i would suggest googling it but it looks like you broke google...

Comment: What browser are you using to test? Have you tried other browsers to see if they are consistent?